# Disk Separation DB installation and data files

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I am wondering whether it is a good idea to separate the database installation media from the actual data files.

In our current environment we have:

1. C: - Windows Server
2. D: - MS SQL Installation & DB Data Files
3. E: - Backups
4. L: - Log files

Would it be a good idea to separate out our D:

- Drive 1: MS SQL installation
- Drive 2: DB Data Files

There are similar questions already posted, but nothing specifically relating to the separation of DB software and DB data files. (similar questions ask whether it is a good idea to separate OS and DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do we separate things onto different disks?
Performance and resilience.

From the Disaster Recovery perspective, if you lose any *one* of your disks, how much damage does it do?

Lose the operating system disk?  OK, that's a biggy. :-(

Lose the backup disk?  Non-event; you still have a running database instance.

Lose the data disk?  Ouch!  But that's OK; you've got your backups ... 
You just need to restore them into a running SQLServer instance ...

Ah.

But you had *that* on the same [data] disk that just failed, taking the data with it!

Keep the installation and data separate.

Whilst it's only semantics, I'd suggest keeping a closer "association" between the Data and Logs disks; they make up all the stuff you really care about.

Move the backups off to another server altogether.  (Whilst it's unlikely these days) If all these disks are *local* to the machine and the machine's *motherboard* were to fail, it wouldn't matter how many disks you had; they'd all be gone!

Comment: That lost point is a little misleading - the data is still on the disks and is therefore available and recoverable if needed.

Comment: @George.Palacios - I once had a control card that thought "1 + 1 =0".  If the controller on the mother board decided to croak, your first question of the day is  "Got (off server) Backups?".  If possible ($$$) the "local backup" should be on a different disk sub-system (controller, SAN, and disks) from that which holds Data.

Comment: @MichaelKutz do not disagree with the principal at all, just that the data is non-recoverable - it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Backups and Tempdb are 2 points i think you need to be re-considering. The below is what  we use in our environment.This works perfectly with all major best practises being implemented.

1. Disk 1 (C) : System files (root)
2. Disk 2 (D) : System databases (except tempdb)
3. Disk 3 (E) : User database data files (mdf,ndf)
4. Disk 4 (F) : User database log files (ldf)
5. Disk 5 (G) : Tempdb (with number of files according to the best practises)

We do not take backups locally which is actually a bad idea considering a server crash beyond recovery. We use Ola hellengren solution and backup to a Global network location where the retention is taken care.

Keeping tempdb is a separate disk will bring the best performce out of it.

Below is a snippet from the storage best practises :

> Separate and prioritize your data among disks Ideally, you should
>   place the tempdb database, content databases, Usage database, search
>   databases, and SQL Server 2014 (SP1), SQL Server 2016, SQL Server 2017
>   RTM, SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP1 and SQL Server 2012 transaction logs
>   on separate physical hard disks. The following list provides some best
>   practices and recommendations for prioritizing data: When you
>   prioritize data among faster disks, use the following ranking: Tempdb
>   data files and transaction logs Database transaction log files Search
>   databases, except for the Search administration database Database data
>   files

Please use this link for a better understanding :

[Top best practises from technet for storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/cc966534(v=technet.10)) : below para is from the tempdb best practise.

> Consider configuration of TEMPDB database Make sure to move TEMPDB to
>   adequate storage and pre-size after installing SQL Server. Performance
>   may benefit if TEMPDB is placed on RAID 1+0 (dependent on TEMPDB
>   usage). For the TEMPDB database, create 1 data file per CPU, as
>   described in #8 below.

Comment: Where is your database installation? On C with the OS?